# azure mobile services server async tasks

Tags: javascript, azure, asynchronous, azure-mobile-services

Inside a table read function I call into another table to get the users email. It appears that the read call is async, so the variable below do not have the necessary data.

How do I make the code in the nested read wait for completion? I feel like this code is a little stinky, there is problem a better way to get the email from the user table and put it in the read response from the userDetail table.

```
function read(query, user, request) {
var userId = user.userId.split(':')[1];
var email = null;
// we only want the user to get their row
console.log('Starting userdetail read ' + new Date().getTime());
query.where({userid : userId}).take(1);
request.execute({
    success: function(results){
   // This code is called but async
        tables.getTable('user').where({id:userId}).read({
            success: function(results){
                console.log('email in read: ' + results[0].email +' '+ new Date().getTime());
                email = results[0].email;
            }
        });
   // This code runs before the above code
        results[0].email = email;
        console.log('email outside of read: ' + email +' '+ new Date().getTime());
        console.log(results[0]);
        request.respond();
    }
});

}
```

Comment: put the last four lines of your execute's success function in your inner success function.

Comment: @dandavis can you post your comment as an answer to this question? Thanks!